# react-native async storage is not saving and no errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

Async storage is not saving. error is empty

i try to store deviceId in async storage but function `setItem` is not working

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const store = async (uniqueId) => { 
const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(uniqueId)
   try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@user", jsonValue, (e,r)=>{ 
        console.log("error: " ,e) 
        return r
      });
   } catch (e) {
      console.log("error: ", e) 
   }
      console.log("get Item: " , AsyncStorage.getItem("@user"))
}
store()
```

Answer (score 2):

`getItem` is an `async` function, so you need to add `await` before like below:

```
const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user")
console.log("get Item: ", JSON.parse(user))
```

Or:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("@user").then((user)=>console.log(JSON.parse(user)))
```

But other than that, I think it's not saved when you call it and the way you call the function is wrong.